# How to determine how long a Joomla user has been logged in

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to get one deceptively simple value into a PHP script, within a Joomla (v3.5.1) environment.  Basically, I need to know how long a user has been logged in for. Even simpler:  How can I find out what time, exactly, the user logged in?

I was looking at the $user object, which does have a lastvisitDate in it, but it doesn't seem to reflect the current login timestamp; instead, that's apparently the previous visit timestamp.  Maybe something in the Joomla $session?  Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: have you checked `#__session` table? it has everything you need :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use google analytics which can also give you real time stats.

1. http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/asynchronous-google-analytics
2. http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/nice-google-analytics
3. http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/advanced-google-analytics
4. http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/google-analytics-dashboard

Joomla has a log manager that logs all user activites http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/logman.

Comment: I appreciate that suggestion... was hoping to get this done w/out any extensions. I'm exploring this myself, as well, and will post a definitive answer if I find one. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a simple misunderstanding, as I was looking at the $user->lastvisitDate, but forgot that the server was on UTC. SO... if anyone wants/needs to know how long a user was logged in, they can indeed just check the lastvisitDate in the $user or #__users table, and calculate from there.